# validate string with a quoted type like "String", "Boolean" in Java

Tags: java, instanceof

I have a scenario where i need to use "Test String" instanceof "String"

is anyway i can do that in java?

The requirement is validate string with a quoted type like "String", "Boolean"

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Best to show some code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test this dynamically where the class name is a string:

```java
String className = "java.lang.Integer";
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Class<?> cls = loader.loadClass(className);
if(cls.isInstance(object)) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that you can only load a class by its [binary name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1), so you must write `"java.lang.String"` instead of just `"String"`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your question I assume you are asking a **Javascript** question rather than a *Java* question. In Java, the use of `instanceof` is relatively rare (and IMO, should be avoided unless absolutely necessary) since Java is a statically typed language.

In Javascript:

```js
typeof object === 'string'
```

In Java:

```java
object instanceof String
```

Comment: It's possible that the OP made this mistake, but on his profile, the most common tags are java, spring-boot, spring, and so on. Therefore I think this question is probably meant to be about Java.